# Is it possible to test my react app with jest and enzyme without ejecting my app?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I would like to know why am I getting the error below. I haven't ejected the project that I created with create-react-app (CRA), I installed enzyme and enzyme-adapter-react-16 only, since jest comes already with CRA.

Note: If I run a test without using enzyme it passes.

this is my .test.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { configure, shallow } from 'enzyme';

import NavigationItems from './NavigationItems';
import NavigationItem from './NavigationItem/NavigationItem';

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

describe('<NavigationItems />', () => {
    it('should render two <NavigationItem /> elements if not authenticated', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<NavigationItems />);
        expect(wrapper.find(NavigationItem)).toHaveLength(2);
    });
});
```

This is the error:

```
gabriels-macbook-pro:BURGER_BUILDER gabrielnessi$ npm test
burger-builder@0.1.0 test /Users/gabrielnessi/Documents/WEBSITE PROJECTS/BURGER_BUILDER
jest

FAIL  src/components/Navigation/NavigationItems/NavigationItems.test.js
● Test suite failed to run

Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

SyntaxError: /Users/gabrielnessi/Documents/WEBSITE PROJECTS/BURGER_BUILDER/src/components/Navigation/NavigationItems/NavigationItems.test.js: Unexpected token (11:32)

   9 | describe('<NavigationItems />', () => {
  10 |     it('should render two <NavigationItem /> elements if not authenticated', () => {
> 11 |         const wrapper = shallow(<NavigationItems />);
     |                                 ^
  12 |         expect(wrapper.find(NavigationItem)).toHaveLength(2);
  13 |     });
  14 | });

  at Parser.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6344:17)
  at Parser.unexpected (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:7659:16)
  at Parser.parseExprAtom (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8828:20)
  at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8413:23)
  at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8393:21)
  at Parser.parseExprOps (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8280:23)
  at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8253:23)
  at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8200:21)
  at Parser.parseExprListItem (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9475:18)
  at Parser.parseCallExpressionArguments (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8620:22)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.683s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

here is my package.json file:
note: I had to install @types/jest because VSCode was not autocompleting jest's properties.

What could be the problem? and how could I fix it without ejecting my project?

Thanks!

```
{
"name": "burger-builder",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@types/jest": "^24.0.16",
  "axios": "^0.19.0",
  "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
  "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
  "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
  "react": "^16.8.6",
  "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
  "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
  "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
  "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
  "redux": "^4.0.4",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "jest",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "development": [
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
  ]
}
}
```

Comment: Please add the error as text.  Consider removing the images as well.

Comment: >and enzyme without ejecting my app?
yes, it's possible

Comment: Did you follow the directions in their docs? https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests#option-1-shallow-rendering

Comment: yes, all the dependencies are installed and also the setup is done. Still getting the error :/

Comment: What does the export in `NavigationItems` look like?  Maybe you are confusing default and named exports?

Comment: NavigationItems are exported as default

Comment: I got a similar error when testing a component because Jest tried to interpret the components .css file as JS file. The solution was to add a moduleNameMapper for jest that supplied every instance of import *.css with an empty mockStyle.js file.